# Signed Applets, JNI and DLLs

Tags: java, dll, resources, java-native-interface, signed-applet

I have a question about signed applets and dll's. 
I'm going to do an applet that uses a bunch of dll's that resides on the harddrive. If my applet is signed and the user agrees to run the applet, will the dll's be able to perform anything?

I was looking for if I might run into any resource/clearance issues if my applet runs the dll's. Basically the dll's are responsible for things like voice recording+voice output (through openAL afaik), and RTP and SIP implementations. So I want to make sure there's no issue with accessing that stuff if my applet is signed and user agrees to run it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the requirements :

- your applet is signed / user aggrees to run it
- the dlls that do the JNI part must be on the java.library.path
- your user must have sufficient privileges to run the dlls

I've done it, so there is no reason you can't do it too